# Let $\Bbb R$ be a field of all real numbers. Prove that $x+1$ is not a unit in $\Bbb R[x]$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, polynomial-rings

Let $\Bbb R$ be a field of all real numbers. Prove that $x+1$ is not a unit in $\Bbb R[x]$.

Attempts:

Suppose that $x+1$ is a unit in $\Bbb R[x]$. Then, there is exists $g(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$ such that $(x+1)g(x) = 1_R$.

Now, we have
\begin{equation*}
deg(x+1) + deg(g(x)) = deg((x+1)g(x)) = deg(1_R) = 0
\end{equation*}
Thus, we have
\begin{align*}
deg(x+1) + deg(g(x)) &= 0 \\
1 + deg(g(x)) &= 0 \\
deg(g(x)) &= -1
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction since $deg(f(x))$ must be non-negative integers for all $f(x) \in \Bbb R[x]$.
Hence, $x+1$ is not a unit in $\Bbb R[x]$.

Is the above true?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is correct.

Another way to see this is that $\Bbb{R}[x]/(x+1)\cong \Bbb{R}$ and hence $(x+1)\ne \Bbb{R}[x]$ so that $x+1$ is not a unit.

Comment: Thanks Sir! Also, for that other ways.